# How to get a mean for a int variable within 6 month based on a variable dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, python-datetime

I would like to know how I could have the mean of `notes` by grouping `dates` within 6 months. In other words, let's say I want the `notes` mean for all the comments between 01/01/2020 and 30/06/2020 and also between 01/07/2020 and 31/12/2020. 
You get the idea :)

I also would like to know the number of comments within 6 months.
But I suppose this is quite the same process.

Here’s some row of my database :
[image: database]

Here’s how I obtained her with web scraping :

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import random


root_url = 'https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/www.gammvert.fr'
urls = [ '{root}?page={i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(1,807) ]

comms = []
notes = []
dates = []

for url in urls: 
    results = requests.get(url)

    time.sleep(20)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    commentary = soup.find_all('section', class_='review__content')

    for container in commentary:

        try:
            comm  = container.find('p', class_ = 'review-content__text').text.strip()

        except:
            comm = container.find('a', class_ = 'link link--large link--dark').text.strip()

        comms.append(comm)

        note = container.find('div', class_ = 'star-rating star-rating--medium').find('img')['alt']
        notes.append(note)

        date_tag = container.div.div.find("div", class_="review-content-header__dates")
        date = json.loads(re.search(r"({.*})", str(date_tag)).group(1))["publishedDate"]

        dates.append(date)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    'dates' : dates
    })

data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')

data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates']).dt.date
data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])


#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Here’s the function I used to obtained my `comms_clean` and `month`:

```
def clean_text(text):
    text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    text = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    text = [word for word,pos in text if (pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS')
]
    text = [word for word in text if not word in stop_words]
    text = [word for word in text if len(word) > 2]
    final_text = ' '.join( [w for w in text if len(w)>2] ) #remove word with one letter
    return final_text

data['comms_clean'] = data['comms'].apply(lambda x : clean_text(x))

data['month'] = data.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

I suppose we can get that with .dt in `datetime` packages but I didn't find out how. Do you have any idea or indication in order to get that ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: I provided the way to create the database I presented..